# How to group by attribute and count a huge list of items

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of crops with their attributes such as location where they were planted, planting technique used, experience and the crop planted itself. I have managed to group them by crop and coordinates (which represents location), but they are grouped separately. Here below is my code that groups and counts them.

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Reference messages collection
// var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('Planting-Calendar-Entries');

database = firebase.database()

var ref = database.ref('Planting-Calendar-Entries');
ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

function gotData(data){
  console.log(data.val())
    var veggie = data.val();
    const counts = Object.values(veggie).reduce((counts, { Veg_planted, coordinates }) => ({
        ...counts,
        [Veg_planted]: (counts[Veg_planted] || 0) + 1,
        [coordinates]: (counts[coordinates] || 0) + 1
      }), {});
      console.log(counts);
  }
function errData(err){
    console.log('Error!');
    console.log(err)
}
```

Here is the output of the above code:

```
"-35.2294059, 173.9472028": 1
"-6.2087634, 106.845599": 3 ​ 
"-1.2920659, 36.8219462": 1 ​
"-0.3688967, 35.286286": 10 ​ 
"-0.3206518, 35.21896820000001": 1 ​
"-0.1634664, 35.5931397": 1 ​ 
"-0.3452364, 35.1519724": 2 
Ageratum: 3 
"Balloon Flower": 2
​Beetroot: 1
"Bells Of Ireland": 2
Broccoli: 1
Cabbage: 12
```

I would love them to be grouped and counted as below:

```
"-0.3688967, 35.286286", Cabbage: 8
"-1.2920659, 36.8219462", Cabbage: 2
"-0.3206518, 35.21896820000001", Broccoli: 1
"-0.3688967, 35.286286", Beetroot: 1
"-0.3452364, 35.1519724", Ageratum: 2
```

If you have an idea of what I can do, I will appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: do you have an original data set?

Comment: Yeah I have a link to my firebase database and that is where the data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, you need to add `Veg_planted` to a combined key with coordinates.

Before the callback function:

```
 var space = ', '
```

Callback for reduce:

```
(counts, { Veg_planted, coordinates }) => {
    const key = [...coordinates, space, Veg_planted].join('');
    counts[key] = (counts[key] ||0) + 1;
    return counts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for your assistance. I wanted to further access these individual groups, ie counts[0]. Will i need another function that will now take in the counts as raw data / input so that I would be able to access each individual group?

Comment: `counts` is an object. what do you mean with `0`?

Comment: i mean, I'd want to get the index of each grouped element in counts, how can i do that, so that i can choose what grouped elements i want to see.

Comment: you could get the keys with `Object.keys(counts)` or take the entries from it. objects have no index.

Comment: Thanks so much for your great assistance!